# how to collect ids

Tags: jquery

How can i collect the ids of clicked spans using jquery?

what i've tried

```
    $('.move-up').click(function(){
        if ($(this).prev())
            $(this).parent().insertBefore($(this).parent().prev());
    });
    $('.move-down').click(function(){
        if ($(this).next())
            $(this).parent().insertAfter($(this).parent().next());
    });

var ids
$('span[id^="text_"]').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    ids += $('span[id^="text_"]');
    alert(ids);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7W7Jz/13/

Comment: It would help if you post at least a snippet of your HTML on the question here rather than just on the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, make an array for ids

```
clicked_ids = new Array();
$('span[id^="text_"]').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    clicked_ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
    alert(clicked_ids); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.move-up').click(function() {
  var myParentSpan = $(this).parents('span');
  var myParentSpanId = myParentSpan.attr('id');
  var mySpanTextContent = myParentSpan.find('span[id^="text"]').html();
  // Your code here.
});
```

Comment: Every time someone uses `$(this).attr('id');` instead of `this.id`, a unicorn dies. (but really. this is complete overuse of jQuery.)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.move-up').click(function() {
  var spanId = this.id;
});
```